# SOAP request is working with SOAP UI but not working in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, api, soap, wsdl

I am implementing SOAP API in PHP. I have SOAP UI(http://soapui.org/.) which is based on Java. I created a new project and run a request to get data. I am getting correct data here. But when I implement this request PHP it is showing error "No XML data received"

I am using the following code:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://ws.spexlive.net/service/soap/catalog?appId=225915&wsdl", array('trace' => 1, "exceptions" => 0));
$result = $client->GetCategories(array('catalog' => 'na', 'siteId' => 0, 'locale'=>"en_us", 'type'=>"default"));

echo "====== REQUEST HEADERS =====" . PHP_EOL;

var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());

echo "========= REQUEST ==========" . PHP_EOL;

var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());

echo "========= RESPONSE =========" . PHP_EOL;

var_dump($result);
```

Thanks

Comment: facing same issue, check if this works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995643/web-service-soap-request-is-working-on-soapui-but-not-working-on-php